# How do I add a bottom border under contact in my vertical navigation bar using css?

Tags: html, css

I am learning to code and can't seem to apply a 1px solid border-bottom under contact.

And if I do, the other bottom borders above become bolder as if they are double bordering.

```
 #navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#navbar a:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

[image: Image of the current result of vertical navigation bar]

```
<div>
      <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="models.html">Models</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need your `last-child` selector on the `li` element.

```css
#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none; /* add this */
}

#navbar li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

See [:last-child at css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/) for more information

Comment: I've done but the other bottom borders are all bold except the bottom one. How can I get rid of the bolded bottom borders above?

Comment: You need to add the ```border-bottom: none;``` to ```#navbar li a``` as above.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much.